# Spatial index's size in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, size, spatial

Is there any way to find out size of spatial index? So far i have been using this query:
`show table status from [dbname]`
however it shows 0 bytes for spatial indexes. Is there other command for spatial ones?

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with all your data, but no indexes.  (Perhaps a copy of your real data).  Check the disk space used.  Then add the spatial data and recheck the disk space.

Dropping an index does not necessarily release the space to the OS, so `DROP INDEX` plus `CREATE INDEX` is likely to show no change is size.  Hence, my suggestion above of starting fresh.

Comment: Hmm. I dropped an created spatial index and checked tables size inbetween. It still shows same value (im getting sizes from `show table status from [dbname]` query).

Comment: drop + create is unlikely to give you the desired metrics.  See added text.